# AWS Cognito userpool creation/update via Cloudformation and setting the AllowAdminCreateUserOnly value

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I have a Cloudformation template to create cognito userpools and want to restrict user creation to admins only.  The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-admincreateuserconfig.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-admincreateuserconfig-allowadmincreateuseronly) states setting to True will enable want I need.

```
AllowAdminCreateUserOnly
    Set to True if only the administrator is allowed to create user profiles. 
    Set to False if users can sign themselves up via an app.

    Required: No

    Type: Boolean

    Update requires: No interruption
```

However, it does not.

```
CognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
       AdminCreateUserConfig:
           AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: True
```

I've tried the inverse (setting to `AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: False`), but again has no effect.  I've resorted to creating the user pool in Cloudformation and then using the CLI to update the property that works, but it's not ideal.
My question is in two parts,

1. Am I making an obvious error with the value I'm setting
2. Assuming I'm not, how does one raise an issue with the Cloudformation team?

Comment: I found the same problem on userpools that I created some time ago. I  just now discovered that the setting is wrong, even though our CF template specifies it like you did.  (Except true instead of True.)  Then as a test I created another pool from a much less complex template and the result was correct.  So, either it's a bug that was fixed, or the problem only exhibits depending on other content in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLI approach was the only way it worked for me.  So deploy the template then call update the user pool using the CLI

Answer (score 0):

You set the flag in wrong way. 
`AllowAdminCreateUserOnly` is property of `AdminCreateUserConfig` so the yaml file must be following:

```
CognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
       AdminCreateUserConfig:
           AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: True
```

Comment: my apologies, it was a bad copy/paste.  I've edited the question